# React adding !important seems to break component re-rendering

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple React component that accepts a prop that hides/shows a component's children. I hide/show using the style attribute and `display: none`. If I use `display: none !important`, the component no longer re-renders when it receives new props.

Within the render method, it looks like this:

```js
var style = {};

if(shouldHide) {
    //this works
    style = {
        display: 'none'
    };
    //this does not
    //style = {
    //  display: 'none !important'
    //};
}

return (
    <span style={style} {...this.props} />
);
```

Here's the full example: https://jsfiddle.net/ccnokes/LnrnrLy2/ (relevant lines start at line 27)

What's going on here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Why do you need `!important` at all? Inline styles have higher precedence than all other styles.

Comment: If a stylesheet has `display: block !important` on it for some reason, inline style won't trump it, right?

Comment: Yes, you're correct. My mistake.

Comment: Why are you rendering the element if it shouldn't be shown?

Comment: @WiredPrairie, I think hide/showing makes sense for use cases like form validation where the element could be hidden and shown multiple times while being used. The pros/cons of each approach have been debated in the comments here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react-js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!important` is currently unsupported - https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/1881

Does not appear they will be adding it any time soon.

They offer this as a workaround:

```js
var sheet = document.createElement('style');
document.body.appendChild(sheet);
sheet.innerHTML = 'html {font-size: 1em !important;}';
```

But not sure if you want to go down that path or not.

I was able to resolve with a class switch:

```css
//css
.hidden {display: none !important};
```

```js
//jsx
var hideClass;

if(shouldHide) {
    hideClass = "hidden";
}

return (
    <span className={hideClass} {...this.props} />
);
```

**Updated**
I went ahead and added the workaround above.
And the fiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/kellyjandrews/oan4grme/

Not exactly the answer you wanted, but it works :)

Comment: Yeah, that works for me as well. I was hoping to avoid using a CSS class because I'm planning on reusing the component across applications and so don't want to make any assumptions about the CSS.

Comment: I would like to know what specifically is keeping the inline style from rendering though.  I tried several iterations but nothing would work quite the way I would expect it.

Comment: Agreed. I'll give this post a bit longer on SO to see if there's a resolution, if not, I'll open an issue on react's GitHub