# React js get the value from div

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am the newer for React js.
How can i achieve the following logic using react js

Here is two div's and one button. When the user click the button these div should toggle .

Comment: Stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react-js should help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`states`](http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/state), like this

```
var Component = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            outsideText: 'Outside',
            insideText: 'Inside'
        }
    },

    handleClick: function () {
        this.setState({
            outsideText: this.state.insideText,
            insideText: this.state.outsideText
        })
    },

    render: function() {
        return <div>
            <div>
                { this.state.outsideText }
                <div>
                    { this.state.insideText }
                </div>
            </div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change Text</button>
        </div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/22100/)