# React toggle component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this simple code below. When I press the Toggle Button the component Child should hide/show, but it's not.

Do I have to re-render something? 
I don't want to switch in/out a CSS class, just toggle via a button click

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

let active = true

const handleClick = () => {
    active = !active
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
    render() {      
        return (    
            <div>  
                <OtherComponent />

                {active && <Child />}

                <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
                    Toggle
                </button>

            </div>            
        )           
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (    
            <div>          
                I am the child
            </div>            
        )             
    }
}

class OtherComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {       
        return (    
            <div>          
                I am the OtherComponent
            </div>            
        )           
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show or hide element in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to get or set it via state:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);

        this.state = {
            active: true,
        };

        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.setState({
            active: !this.state.active
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <OtherComponent />

                {this.state.active && <Child />}

                <button type="button" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Toggle
                </button>

            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Note** that with this approach you will re:render the entire parent component (as well as it's children).
Consider using another approach, when you are passing a `prop` to the child component and it will render itself with content based on this prop (it can render an empty `div` or something).
There are number of libraries that make this job easy for you, like [react-collapse](https://github.com/nkbt/react-collapse) with animations and stuff.

Comment: I get an error "unexpected token" at   handleClick = () => {

Comment: its a typo. i fixed it. notice the change i made on `onClick` with `this.`

Comment: Yes, I spotted it just after posting, thanks it's working. And I'll read up on your Note, cheers

Answer (score 2):

You should only use `state` and `props` to manage your app state.

So instead try:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
        active: true
    };
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  const handleClick = () => {
    this.setState({active = !this.state.active});
  }

  render() {      
    return (    
      <div>  
        <OtherComponent />
        {this.state.active && <Child />}
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
          Toggle
        </button>
      </div>            
    );          
  }
}
```

---

Alernatively, you *could* use `forceUpdate()` to force a re-render, but this is **strongly discouraged:**

```
const handleClick = () => {
  active = !active;
  this.forceUpdate();
}
```