# Toggle element isHidden True/False with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with this code, my Toggle button doesn't display the Child element but gives me a full blank page
Here is the code

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
            this.state = {items: [] , isHidden: true};
            this.toggleHidden = this.toggleHidden.bind(this);
    }

componentDidMount() {
        fetch("/customers") 
            .then(result=>result.json())
            .then(items=>this.setState({items}));
}

    toggleHidden () {

        this.setState({
          isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
        });

      }


    render() {

        return (
      <div id='customerDetails'>
      {this.state.items.map(item=><customerDetail>
            <div id={item._id} >
              <button onClick={this.toggleHidden} data-arg1={item._id} value='U'/>
              {item.cost} 
              {!this.state.isHidden && <Child >
                  <div className='modal'>
                  <form onSubmit={this._handleUpdate}>
                  <input type='text' id='cost' name='cost'/>
                  <input type='hidden' id="_id" name='_id' value=item.id />
                  <input type='submit' value='Update'/>
                </form>
                </div>
                  </Child>
              }
              </div>
        </customerDetail>)}

        </div>
        );
      }

}
```

Any idea , i do not know if it's coming from the fact all that happens in an iteration
I also tried this standalone source code from StackOverflow [React toggle component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44048621/react-toggle-component) that should work, and it does not work....blank page

Any idea

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the code for customerDetail and Child component

Comment: I have no additional code, all is in my code above, perhaps there is a problem with this.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need fix errors in the code.
Change line `<input type='hidden' id="_id" name='_id' value=item.id />` to `<input type='hidden' id="_id" name='_id' value={item.id} />`

Answer (score 0):

i just tried this in my parent component render function:

```
<button onClick={this.toggleHidden} value='U'/>
              {item.cost} 
              {!this.state.isHidden && <Child />}
```

and on the bottom of the code i add a Child class:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (    
                  <div className='modal'>
                  <form >
                  <input type='text' id='cost' name='cost'/>
                  <input type='hidden' id="_id" name='_id' />
                  <input type='submit' value='Update'/>
                  </form>
                  </div>           
        )             
    }
}
```

But i have stil a blank page when toggle

Answer (score 0):

I made my code work, here it is :
Remove Child component at the bottom of the page
Add a function CHild at the beginning :

```
function Child(props) {
  return (
    <div className='modal'>
      <form onSubmit={props.onClick}>
        <input type='text' id='cost' name='cost'/>
        <input type='hidden' id="_id" name='_id' value={props.value} />
        <input type='submit' value='Update'/>
      </form>
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Added the function renderChild in my parent component :

```
renderChild(i) {
  return (
    <Child
      value={i}
      onClick={() => this.props.onClick(i)}
    />
  );
}
```

Finally in the render of my parent component , replace the line :

```
{!this.state.isHidden && <Child/>}
```

by

```
{!this.state.isHidden && this.renderChild(item._id)}
```

Now my toggle function works