# Show or Hide a particular element in react

Tags: reactjs, toggle

I have to show list of faqs and I need to hide the answers of the questions. When I click on the question, the answer for that particular question need to be shown. My problem is, I have a bunch of questions and when i click the button, it will show all of the answer instead of the specific answer to that question.

```
class Faqs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true
    }
  }
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }
render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <span onClick={() => this.toggleHidden()}><strong>This is the question</strong></span>
               {!this.state.isHidden && <p>Answer for the question</p>} <br/>

               <span onClick={() => this.toggleHidden()}><strong>Question2</strong></span>
               {!this.state.isHidden && <p>Answer2</p>} <br/>
               <hr></hr>            
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show or hide element in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can break your component to one more level to have a sub component which renders only the question and corresponding answer. Pass the question and answers as props. In that way you can use the same component for all questions and yet every question/answer pair will have their own state.

```
class Faq extends Component{
 state = {isHidden: true}
 toggleHidden = ()=>this.setState((prevState)=>({isHidden: !prevState.isHidden}))
 render(){
  return(
     <div>
     <span onClick={this.toggleHidden}>
           <strong>{props.question}</strong></span>
           {!this.state.isHidden && <p>{props.answer}</p>}   
     </div>
  )
 }
}




class Faqs extends Component {

render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <Faq question={"Question 1"} answer={"answer 1"} />
              <Faq question={"Question 2"} answer={"answer 2"} />
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you would list FAQs in some kind of list - then as you iterate over them, each will have an index number assigned to it - then as you toggle individual answers, you store that index in the state and operate on DOM via that number.

edit. In current day and age, it's only appropriate to show example using hooks:

```js
const {useState} = React;

const FaqApp = () => {
  const [ selectedQuestion, toggleQuestion ] = useState(-1);
  
  function openQuestion(index) {
    toggleQuestion(selectedQuestion === index ? -1 : index);
  }

  const faqs = getFaqs();

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>FAQs:</h2>
        {faqs.map(( { question, answer}, index) => (
          <div key={`item-${index}`} className={`item ${selectedQuestion === index ? 'open' : ''}`}>
            <p className='question' onClick={() => openQuestion(index)}>{question}</p>
            <p className='answer'>{answer}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
    </div>
  )
}

function getFaqs() {
  const faqs = [
    {
      question: 'Question 1',
      answer: 'answer 1'
    },
    {
      question: 'Question 2',
      answer: 'answer 2'
    }
  ];
  return faqs;
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <FaqApp />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```css
body {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

h2 {
   margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.item + .item {
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.question {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
   display: none;
}

.open .answer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

---

older version of this post:

I've written a quick example that allows you to have multiple questions:

```js
class FaqApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      // start the page with all questions closed
     selectedQuestion: -1
    };
    this.openQuestion = this.openQuestion.bind(this);
  }
 
  getFaqs() {
   // some service returning a list of FAQs
   const faqs = [
      {
        question: 'Question 1',
        answer: 'answer 1'
      },
      {
        question: 'Question 2',
        answer: 'answer 2'
      }
    ];
    return faqs;
  }
  
  openQuestion(index) {
    // when a question is opened, compare what was clicked and if we got a match, change state to show the desired question.
   this.setState({
     selectedQuestion: (this.state.selectedQuestion === index ? -1 : index)
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    // get a list of FAQs
    const faqs = this.getFaqs();
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>FAQs:</h2>
          {faqs.length && faqs.map((item, index) => (
            <div key={`item-${index}`} className={`item ${this.state.selectedQuestion === index ? 'open' : ''}`}>
                <p className='question' onClick={() => this.openQuestion(index)}>
                  {item.question}
                </p>
                <p className='answer'>
                  {item.answer}
                </p>
            </div>
          ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<FaqApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

h2 {
   margin-bottom: 11px;
}

.item + .item {
  margin-top: 11px;
}

.question {
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.answer {
   display: none;
}

.open .answer {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: IMO this is a more appropriate ReactJS way of solution.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using **one** boolean piece of state to control the logic for multiple pieces. This is a classic scenario to use separate components.

Create a new component `ToggleQuestion` that encapsulates the mechanic of show/reveal.

The `Faqs` component instead manages a list of `ToggleQuestion` components.

```js
const QUESTIONS = [
  { title: 'q1', answer: 'a1' },
  { title: 'q2', answer: 'a2' }
]

class ToggleQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { isHidden: true }
  }
  
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({ isHidden: !this.state.isHidden })
  }
  
  render () {
    const { question, answer } = this.props
    const { isHidden } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{question}</span>
        { !isHidden && <span>{answer}</span> }
        <button onClick={this.toggleHidden.bind(this)}>
          Reveal Answer
        </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class Faqs extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        { QUESTIONS.map(question => (
          <ToggleQuestion
            question={question.title}
            answer={question.answer}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Faqs />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a different handler for the answer. In the future if you need more logic for the answer will be scalable. Notice **renderAnswer**

```
class Faqs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isHidden: true
    }
  }
  toggleHidden () {
    this.setState({
      isHidden: !this.state.isHidden
    })
  }
  renderAnswer() {
    if (this.state.isHidden) {
      return;
    }
    return (
      <p>Answer</p>
    );
  }
  render() {
    return (
            <div>
               <span onClick={() => this.toggleHidden()}><strong>This is the question</strong></span>
               { this.renderAnswer() } <br/>

               <span onClick={() => this.toggleHidden()}><strong>Question2</strong></span>
               { this.renderAnswer() } <br/>
               <hr></hr>            
            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do what you want. (This one will only make it possible to have one open at a time)

```
class Faqs extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hiddenId: null,
    }
  }
  setHiddenId(id) {
    this.setState({
      hiddenId: id
    })
  }
  render() {
        return (
            <div>
               <span onClick={() => this.setHiddenId('one')}><strong>This is the question</strong></span>
               {this.state.hiddenId === 'one' && <p>Answer for the question</p>} <br/>

           <span onClick={() => this.setHiddenId('two')}><strong>Question2</strong></span>
           {this.state.hiddenId === 'two' && <p>Answer2</p>} <br/>
           <hr></hr>            
        </div >
    )
    }
}
```