# React JS Best Practice

Tags: reactjs

I am planning to use my state as a form of signaling that I will gonna change back and forth to show my loading screen, main form and success or error message. But not sure if this is the best practice. Here is a sample code

```
div hidden={this.state.FormStatus.statusMode !== "Loading"}>
          <LoadingScreen />
        </div> 

div hidden={this.state.FormStatus.statusMode !== "Main"}>
          <MainForm/>
        </div>
```

But I am not sure if this is the best way, I am worried that it can slowdown my application or eat my clients CPU with this one. Can you suggest better method?

Comment: Instead of hidden you can use if else. to prevent the form from loading into dom.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show or hide element in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react)

Comment: Do you want to have the div's present in the DOM? Otherwise I wouldn't load them at all.

Comment: Have a look at the "Simple Everyday Patterns" section on this page: https://lucasmreis.github.io/blog/simple-react-patterns/

Comment: I added div because custom component cannot use hidden property

Answer (score 4):

```
render() {
  const { statusMode } = this.state.FormStatus;

  if (statusMode === 'Loading') {
    return <LoadingScreen />;
  } else if (statusMode === 'Main' {
    return <MainForm />;
  }
}
```

or

```
render() {
  const { statusMode } = this.state.FormStatus;

  return (
    <div>
      <span>Something you want to display no matter what</span>
      {statusMode === 'Loading' && <Loading />}
      {statusMode === 'Main' && <Main />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is really nice ill try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the performance improvement is over what you are doing but here is an idea.

```
render() {
  const { FormStatus: { statusMode } } = this.state;
  const component = { Loading: <LoadingScreen />, Main: <MainForm /> };

  return component[this.state.FormStatus.statusMode];
}
```

For the record, what you are doing is fine. Only real improvement is to only render one `div` instead of two.

Answer (score 0):

If you using hook then,

```js
const Example = () => {
     const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true)

     return (
        <>
           {loading && <Loading />}
           {!loading && <Main/> }
        </>
     )   
}
```