# How to modify an existing div element in html by react?

Tags: reactjs

Is it possible to use react to show and hide an existing div element by id?

For example, I want use react to have this `<div id="example">this is example</div>` show and hide by button click and this element is not created by react.

Comment: is this what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react.

Comment: thank you for your information, but this is not the answer, this is not about modifying the existing div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to understand React's philosophy. I strongly suggest you read the official React tutorial: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html. 
In this case you would like to appear and disappear a div, this can be accomplished by changing internal state of a React Component. Then you need to create a function that is bound to the context of the instance of the Component.
For example:

```
class Example extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: true,
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      open: !open,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { open } = this.state;
    return (
      <main>
        <button onClick={this.toggle.bind(this)}>{open ? 'Hide' : 'Show'}</button>
        {open && <div id="example"><h1>this is example</h1></div>}
      </main>
    );
  }
}
```

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PxWdZK?editors=1010

Comment: thank you for your information, maybe i did not describe correctly, so it should be something like this:    <div id="example">example</div>   <div id="root"></div>, so how can i hide and show the first "example" in the class that "root" has ?

Comment: why would you need React then ? Just do some: `document.querySelector('#example').style.display = 'none';`

Comment: Thank you so much ^_^, i find out how to do it from your tip.