# Hide a specific button from TabBar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to find out how to hide a specific button from a `BottomTabBar` in react-navigation.

I know that I can create hidden screen in `StackNavigator` instead of `TabBarNavigator` but then my `BottomTabBar` won't be visible on that hidden screen.

Does anyone know how to implement so?

Comment: Please add code related to your question! [Ask a good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Currently I need only the concept of implementation.

Comment: This could be helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react

Answer (score 0):

In the [Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/tab-navigator.html)

You have the option `TabVisible: boolean = true` you can see to false.

Can't go further without sample code. But reading the Docs is a good start.

Comment: There is no any information in the Docs about **tabVisible**. Only **tabBarVisible** but it's not the same. I need to hide only one button from the bar, not the whole bar.