# TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined in sweetAlert

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a simple crud app that has data coming in and getting filled in a react-table and it has simple crud operations of add and delete.

But I am getting this error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```
import SweetAlert from "react-bootstrap-sweetalert";
```

then wrote a method: (it's outside the class)

```
const successAlert = () => {
  console.log("alertttttttttttttttttttttttt");
  this.setState({
    alert: (
      <SweetAlert
        alert={this.state.alert}
        success
        title="Good job!"
        onConfirm={this.onConfirm}
        onCancel={this.onCancel}
      >
        You clicked the button!
      </SweetAlert>
    ),
  });
};
```

and this is my the class:

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  alert: null,
  data: dataTable.map((prop, key) => {
    return {
      id: key,
      name: prop[0],
      position: prop[1],
      office: prop[2],
      age: prop[3],
      actions: (
        <div className="actions-right">
          <Button
            fill="true"
            onClick={() => {
              var data = this.state.data;
              data.find((o, i) => {
                if (o.id === key) {
                  data.splice(i, 1);
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log(i);
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              });
              successAlert();
              this.setState({
                data: data,
              });
            }}
            color="danger"
            size="sm"
            className="btn-icon btn-link remove"
            id="tooltip974171201"
          >
            <i className="fa fa-times" />
          </Button>
          <UncontrolledTooltip
            delay={0}
            target="tooltip974171201"
            placement="top"
          >
            Delete this record
          </UncontrolledTooltip>
        </div>
      ),
    };
  }),
};
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mentioned that `(it's outside the class)`.
**this** keyword has scope only within the class hence it's giving you the error. Move that method inside the class.
Ex:

```
this.state = {
    showAlert: false
}

showAlert() {
    this.setState({ showAlert: true });
}

render() {
    return(
        <SweetAlert
        alert={this.state.showAlert}>
            You clicked the button!
        </SweetAlert>
        <button onClick={this.showAlert.bind(this)}>Show Alert</button>
    )
}
```

Comment: that worked. but the alert box still does not appear.

Comment: you don't need to set whole component as state. Keep that in render method and set a boolean state.
https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-show-and-hide-reactjs-components
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react

Comment: ohkk.. Can you please put that into perspective?

Comment: thanks. I want it to pop up only on a button click. Right now, it's loading at the time of page render itself.