# Unexpected behaviour of sort icon changing direction when filtering table

Tags: reactjs, sorting, redux, react-redux

The problem I'm facing is if I filter and return some results, then sort, If I then update the filter, the icon changes to go the other direction, without me clicking on it. I think I have to put ascending to be a global state too (not sure), and some logic will need to be involved that it only applies to the currently sorted field that I can get from the fieldText global state. Help is much appreciated :)

TableHeader.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useStoreState, useStoreActions } from 'easy-peasy';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { FaIcon } from './icons';

const HeaderWrapper = styled.div``;
const Div = styled.div``;
const Icon = styled(FaIcon)``;

const TableHeader = ({ title, field, getSortedPeople }) => {
  const [ascending, setAscending] = useState(null);

  const nullCheck = () => {
    if (!ascending) return 'asc';
    if (ascending === 'asc') return 'desc';
    return 'asc';
  };

  const positionArrow = () => {
    if (!ascending) return ['far', 'chevron-down'];
    if (ascending === 'asc') return ['far', 'chevron-up'];
    return ['far', 'chevron-down'];
  };

  const sortBy = () => {
    setAscending(nullCheck());
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (ascending) getSortedJobs(field, ascending);
  }, [ascending]);
  return (
    <HeaderWrapper onClick={() => sortBy()}>
      <Div>{title}</Div>
      <Icon icon={positionArrow()} />
    </HeaderWrapper>
  );
};

TableHeader.propTypes = {
  title: PropTypes.string,
  field: PropTypes.array,
  getSortedPeople: PropTypes.func,
};

TableHeader.defaultProps = {
  title: '',
  field: [],
  getSortedPeople: () => {},
};

export default TableHeader;
```

People Model:

```
import { action } from 'easy-peasy';

const defaultValues = {
  results: [],
  tableLoading: false,
  filter: false,
  filteredText: '',
  fieldText: '',
  sortByText: '',
  sortBy: null,
  resultsLoading: true,
};

const PeopleModel = {
  ...defaultValues,
  setPeopleResults: action((state, payload) => {
    state.results = payload;
  }),
  setResultsLoading: action((state, payload) => {
    state.resultsLoading = payload;
  }),
  setTableLoading: action((state, payload) => {
    state.tableLoading = payload;
  }),
  setFilter: action((state, payload) => {
    state.filter = payload;
  }),
  setFilteredText: action((state, payload) => {
    state.filteredText = payload;
  }),
  setFieldText: action((state, payload) => {
    state.fieldText = payload;
  }),
  setSortByText: action((state, payload) => {
    state.sortByText = payload;
  }),
  setSortBy: action((state, payload) => {
    state.sortBy = payload;
  }),
  setDefaultResults: action(() => {
    // return default values as state to avoid mismatched data
    return { ...defaultValues };
  }),
};

export default PeopleModel;
```

PeoplesPage:

```
import React, { useEffect, useContext } from 'react';
import { useStoreState, useStoreActions } from 'easy-peasy';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router';
import styled, { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components';
import { reverse } from 'named-urls';
import { checkErrors } from './hooks-api';
import shallowEqual from 'shallowequal';
import PeopleResultsLoader from './PeopleResultsLoader';
import routes from '../../../routes/routes';
import FilteringPeople from './FilteringPeople';
import StandardPage from '../../standard-page/StandardPage';
import StandardContentInner from '../../standard-page/StandardContentInner';
import PeopleListDataTable from './PeopleListDataTable';
import usePeopleApi from './/usePeopleApi';
import PeopleListNoResults from './PeopleListNoResults';
import PeopleFilterNoResults from './PeopleListFilterNoResults';

const Heading = styled.h1``;

const ButtonWrapper = styled.div``;

const FilterPadding = styled.div``;

const PeopleTablePadding = styled.div``;

const PeoplePage = ({ history }) => {

  const { filterPeople } = usePeopleApi();

  const {
    results,
    resultsLoading,
    filter,
    filteredText,
    fieldText,
    sortByText,
  } = useStoreState(
    ({ PeopleModel }) => ({
      results: PeopleModel.results,
      resultsLoading: PeopleModel.resultsLoading,
      filter: PeopleModel.filter,
      filteredText: PeopleModel.filteredText,
      fieldText: PeopleModel.fieldText,
      sortByText: PeopleModel.sortByText,
    }),
    shallowEqual,
  );

  const {
    setResultsLoading,
    setPeopleResults,
    setTableLoading,
    setFilter,
  } = useStoreActions(
    ({ PeopleModel }) => ({
      setResultsLoading: PeopleModel.setResultsLoading,
      setJobResults: PeopleModel.setPeopleResults,
      setTableLoading: PeopleModel.setTableLoading,
      setFilter: PeopleModel.setFilter,
    }),
    shallowEqual,
  );

  const getAllPeopleReports = async () => {
    setTableLoading(true);
    if (filteredText.length > 0) setFilter(true);
    else setFilter(false);
    const res = await filterPeople({
      text: filteredText,
      field: fieldText,
      sortBy: sortByText,
    });
    if (!res || (await checkErrors(res))) {
      setResultsLoading(false);
    } else {
      setResultsLoading(false);
      setPeopleResults(res.content);
    }
    setTableLoading(false);
  };

  const renderFilter = () => {
    if (!resultsLoading && ((results && results.length > 0) || filter))
      return (
        <>
          <FilterPadding>
            <Heading>My People</Heading>
            <PeopleJobs />
          </FilterPadding>
        </>
      );
    return null;
  };

  const isLoading = () => {
    if (resultsLoading) return <PeopleResultsLoader />;
    if (results && results.length > 0)
      return (
        <PeopleTablePadding>
          <PeopleListDataTable />
        </PeopleTablePadding>
      );
    if (filter) return <PeopleListFilterNoResults />;
    return <PeopleListNoResults />;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let isMounted = true;
    if (isMounted) getAllPeopleReports();

    return function cleanup() {
      isMounted = false;
    };
  }, [filteredText, fieldText, sortByText]);

  useEffect(() => {
    return function cleanup() {
      setResultsLoading(true);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <StandardPage>
      <StandardContentInner>
        <>{renderFilter()}</>
        <>{isLoading()}</>
      </StandardContentInner>
    </StandardPage>
  );
};

PeoplesPage.defaultProps = { history: null };

PeoplesPage.propTypes = {
  history: PropTypes.object,
};

export default withRouter(PeoplesPage);
```

Comment: Since you are you conditionally rendering your `PeopleListDataTable` whenever new results are coming in, when you change a filter, the `TableHeader` gets unmounted and then remounted as a new instance when the results come in, losing the local component state. If you can instead hide the `PeopleListDataTable` component when results are loading instead of removing it from the render tree then it will retain its state and you shouldn't have to hoist that state out of the `TableHeader` component to keep it around.

Comment: Can you show me please as example :) This sounds what I need.

Comment: Use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24590605/11847125 to not display the `PeopleListDataTable` via css instead of removing it from the render tree entirely.

Comment: I have tried this and doesn't seem to work for my expected behaviour.

Comment: @StevenDornan you asked the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66696855/table-component-re-renders-every-time-i-filter-which-then-affects-the-direction?noredirect=1#comment117903306_66696855) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66694761/component-re-renders-every-time-i-filter-which-affects-the-behaviour-of-my-sorti?noredirect=1#comment117899964_66694761) the cause of your problem was already told to you twice yet you keep deleting the question and ask it again.

Comment: @StevenDornan To solve this maybe you can provide a minimal reproducible example using a [code snippet](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/cf93d154958207b4f938ec58e45ffbde).  If you tried not to unmount and instead hiding your components then why did your double repost of the same question not show this? It would be easy to put the table state in context but without a minimal reproducible example I don't think anyone will be in a hurry to try and solve it if all they get is "doesn't work".