# how to make edit/ delete component which will hover when we pres s 3 dots on each item in FlatList

Tags: react-native

How could I make the edit/delete component, which would hover when the user presses the 3 dots icon on each item in my FlatList?

Just like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: You can do like, 1. take index from renderItem(item,index) 2. delete the the element from the array you are passing to FlatList "data" prop

Comment: i can do the edit delete functionality , but not understanding how to make that overlay

Comment: You need to put the dropdown component as child of row component and give it position absolute. like `style={{position:"absolute",top:0,right:0}}`

Answer (score 0):

Like earlier comments suggest, you need an overlay that has some styling on it, such as `style={{position:"absolute",top:0,right:0}}`
But in order to show/hide the overlay you will need to toggle another class that controls a `display: none` style.

Perhaps this [link will help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24502898/show-or-hide-element-in-react)

###### Bottom line

Essentially, you need to use `React.useState` to monitor whether or not the overlay should be visible, and the 3 dots button needs to toggle the state.
The state should be wrapped inside your Coupon component such that it is toggled for each item in your Array. I personally prefer using the `.map(...)` function when iterating over lists in React.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
import React,{useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View,StyleSheet,FlatList } from 'react-native';
const items = [
  { id: 1, name: 'imran' },
  { id: 2, name: 'shad' },
];
export default App = ({
    params,
}) => {
  const [visibleIndex,setVisibleIndex]=useState(-1)
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList
        data={items}
        renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
          return (
            <View style={styles.column}>
              <Text>{item.name}</Text>
              {visibleIndex === index ? (
                <View
                  style={styles.floatComponent}>
                  <Text style={styles.btn} onPress={() => console.log(index)}>Delete</Text>
                  <Text style={styles.btn} onPress={() => console.log('edit')}>Edit</Text>
                </View>
              ) : (
                <Text onPress={()=>{
                  console.log(index)
                  setVisibleIndex(index)
                  console.log({visibleIndex})
                }} style={[styles.floatComponent,{ fontSize: 30 }]}>...</Text>
              )}
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: 40,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  column:{
     width: '100%', height: 70, backgroundColor: 'red',
     margin:5,justifyContent:"center",padding:10
  },
  floatComponent: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 8,
    textAlign:"center",
    textAlignVertical:"center",
  },
  btn:{
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    margin:1,
    padding:5
  }
});
```