# Cannot add our own react element onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am working on a tasklist page. The main page has a form in which the user would add  the task and click on the add task button and the corresponding task would be appended to the "todo-task" div. I am using my own created react element  (Do laundry is just for example) which returns a checkbox followed by the text passed as prop. In the following code I am trying to append  at the end of our todo-task div but it is showing me some error. Is my approach right? If not what approach should I take?

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import './Tasklist.css'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import AddBoxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AddBox';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';
import Task from './Task.js';

function Tasklist() {
const [task, settask] = useState("")

let pendingTask = document.getElementById('pending-task')
let doneTask = document.getElementById('done-task')

const addTask = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault()
    let tmp_text=task.trim()

    if(tmp_text==="")return

    let task_tmp = document.createElement(<Task text={tmp_text} />);
    pendingTask.appendChild(task_tmp);
    settask("");
}

const keyDownEvent=(e)=>{
    let key=e.key

    if(key==='Enter' && !e.shiftKey)addTask(e);
}
return (
    <>
        <div className="add-task">
            <form >
                <textarea 
                    type="text" 
                    value={task}
                    rows={1}
                    placeholder="Add Task" 
                    onChange={(e)=>settask(e.target.value)}
                    onKeyDown={keyDownEvent}
                    />
                <Button variant="outline-primary" onClick={addTask}>
                    <AddBoxIcon /> Add Task
                </Button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div className="todo-task" id="pending-task">

        </div>
        
        <Task text="Enjjoyyyy!!!" />

        <hr />

        <div className="done-task" id = "done-task">
            <ul id="done-task-list">

            </ul>
        </div> 
    </>
)
}

export default Tasklist
```

Comment: What error is being shown?

Comment: You've got another good answer below, but it's effectively the same as yesterday's answers to the same question: [How to add our own react element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68383189/how-to-add-our-own-react-element).  Is there something still unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going about this in a fundamentally incorrect way, so it's not a quick fix.  Now is the time to take a big step back and start over on your component.

What you're currently trying to do is *modify the DOM directly*.  **Don't do that in React.**  What you should instead be doing is maintaining *state*.

Instead of trying to directly create an element and add it to the DOM, create a record and update state with that record.  This is an entirely separate task than rendering the DOM.  The actual rendering is done *based* on that current state.

Currently in your state you have "a task".  But you're trying to build functionality to add more tasks.  So really your state should have a *list* of tasks, and you can add to that list.  (Which can be in addition to the single task, of course.  You can use `useState` as many times as you like.)

For example, consider state like this:

```
const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
```

Then add a task in your button click handler:

```
const addTask = (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    let tmp_text=task.trim();
    if(tmp_text==="") return;

    setTasks([...tasks, tmp_task]); // <--- here
    settask("");
}
```

This keeps a running array of the tasks being stored.

Then in the rendering, you would `.map` over those tasks to show them:

```
<div className="todo-task" id="pending-task">
    {tasks.map((t, i) => (
        <Task key={i} text={t} />
    ))}
</div>
```